# Live streaming issue from iOS to Android

Tags: android, ios, h.264, live-streaming, wowza

We are working on an video streaming application in iOS and Android. We are using Wowza server.  Application works fine from iOS to iOS and Android to Android. Means a video published from iOS device can be viewed on iOS device but not on Android device.

I know both Android and iOS support H.264 compression and we are publishing H.264 formatted stream. Here a bit confusion I thin H.264 is a compression technique and further defined by MP4, FLV etc please confirm.

What I think iOS publish stream something like .MOV defined H.264 stream which is not supported by Android that's why I think it doesn't work on Android. Please confirm.

Please suggest any way to play a video stream published through ios app to Android device.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to video files: The container and the encoding (or codec). H.264 is an encoding, and Android can deal with it, but Apple uses the QuickTime container format, which is similar to the MP4 container but apparently just different enough that Android can't handle it. Android can play MP4 files, and there are utilities to convert QuickTime to MP4, if that helps.